# Add key value to query param string from the start

Tags: javascript

I hold a set of key values pairs in a String format in my router.

Able to extract those values as follows.

```
const params = router.location.search; // example value:  ?one=1&two=2&three=3
```

I need to append another set of key values to this. Thus I end up with the following instead.

```
const params = `${router.location.search}&token=${token}`; // value: ?one=1&two=2&three=3&token=${token}
```

But I want to maintain the order such that the token value is the first query param as follows instead.

```
?token=${token}&one=1&two=2&three=3
```

I can't just move the token to be first in the concatenation cos of the question mark. Would end up as follows which is wrong.

```
// wrong cos of the question mark placing. 
const params = `token=${token}&${router.location.search}`; // value: token=${token}?one=1&two=2&three=3
```

At present I am doing the following which works but so messy. I am using sub string to

remove the question mark from the router value and add it to the start of the newly created 
String. Is there a better elegant solution to this?

```
const str = router.location.search;
const params = `?token=${token}&${str.substring(1, str.length)}`;
```

P.S: I know order in query params doesn't matter but this is needed for visual purposes in the url and some analytic requirements.

Comment: Are you aware of [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams) and how to use it to convert back and forth between a string representation of a query and an object representation of a query?

Comment: @Wyck Unfortunately it has an `append()` method, but no `prepend()` method. So to accomplish this he'll need to loop through the object, copying all the parameters to a new object.

Comment: What you're doing looks like the simplest solution.

Comment: You're missing the `&` after `${token}`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. That was a typo on my part. Do have the & in my code. It works, was wondering if there is something more elegant than dealing with substrings. Also the router.location.search could possibly be empty. Meaning an ugly & at the end is going to dangle around unless I add even more checks in place to handle that.

Comment: I don't think there's any harm in a dangling `&`, but you could check for it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use URLSearchParams.

```js
function getParams(searchQuery, token) {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(searchQuery);
  return `?token=${token}&${searchParams.toString()}`;
}

console.log(getParams('?one=1&two=3&three=3', 'ab'));
```